# Is java 1.7 supported in coverity_platform-7.0.3

Tags: java, coverity

While doing coverity analysis, I am getting the below message:

`37 Java compilation units (6%) have been captured and are ready for analysis`

When I am checking build-log.txt , I can see below error message :

```
[WARNING] Source level >= 1.7 is not supported. Source will be parsed as 1.6.
error: expected an identifier
            }catch(NullPointerException | SQLException ex){
                                        ^
```

This error shows that java 1.7 not supported. Is the problem related with coverity or some configuration in my setup ? Kindly confirm.

Comment: If you're getting *that* kind of error message...I would guess it isn't supported.  What would lead you to believe otherwise?

Comment: @Makoto just wanted to be double sure and if there is any work around , please suggest so that it can support java 1.7

Comment: What version of Coverity analysis are you running?

Comment: @MarkRobinson coverity_analysis-7.0.3 is being used

Comment: @MarkRobinson Kindly suggest any approach to resolve this scenario